# Как открыть картинку в другой вкладке php?

Tags: php, html

Есть небольшая галерея(index.php) Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на любую картинку она открывалась полноразмерно в другой вкладке(photo.php)? А не просто target = _blank.Нужно чтобы ссылки у всех картинок были на тот же php файл , но отображали именно ту картинку на которую нажали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример для get запросов

Ссылка будет вида:

```
/photo.php?img=somefile.jpg
```

В php коде файла photo.php, где-нибудь в начале

```
<?php
      $img = $_GET['img']
?>
<img src='/path/to/image/<?= $img ?>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Get параметры в запросе, что бы передать имя файла, и при помощи Заголовков открывайте изображение.

Comment: В этом ответе отлично смотрелся бы небольшой кусок кода, иллюстрирующий решение. (В вопросе, впрочем, тоже). :)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?